# "Redirect an address to a server" - which preposition should I use?

Tags: translation

I want to say the following in german

> I want to redirect the address xxx.domain.de to the server xyz.domain.de

Is the use of *umbiegen nach* correct in this case?

Comment: In which dictionary did you read that?

Comment: @feeela: In no dictionary, I heard it used.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"umbiegen" is possible, but somewhat colloquial in my opinion.

The most direct translation (and a common one as well) would be "umleiten":

> Ich will die Adresse xxx.domain.de auf den Server xyz.domain.de umleiten.

Regarding the proposition I'd say it's a tricky question:

If you focus on the *address* `xyz.domain.de` then I'd say "auf xyz.domain.de umleiten".

If the important part is that the *server* called `xyz.domain.de` will handle it, then I'd say "zu xyz.domain.de umleiten" or even "zum Server xyz.domain.de" umleiten.

Unfortunately that's just my intuition as a native speaker, so I can't tell you the appropriate rules for this.

Comment: In my ears, "umbiegen" sounds rather strange in this context, not just somewhat colloquial.

Comment: @Hendrik: I've heard it used a few times with this exact meaning (I work as a software developer), but I wouldn't write it to a customer/client or in any other professional communication.

Comment: @Hendrik: I also heard it from the mouth of one of my german colleague. Joachim: good to know the level of formality of *umbiegen*/*umleiten*. The mail I wanted to write was for some colleague anyway. One question though, would it be correct to use *auf* with *umbiegen* too, or to use *nach* as I first thought.

Comment: @Joachim: Ah, OK - then it seems I'm a customer `:-)`

Comment: @Joachim I don't know where you've ever heard "umbiegen" in that context, but it has a completely different meaning (as of "to bend sth." or [also] "to turn around"). You just can't bend digital information, so I agree with Hendrik, that the usage of "umbiegen" is quite strange in that context, especially for a German speaker. Nonetheless +1 for providing the correct answer afterwards. [LEO also mentions "umschalten"](http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&search=redirect) as a technical term, but thats unusual for domain-redirects too, it's more usable for signal-shifting in general.

Comment: I know the term "umbiegen" is being used in conjunction with pointers, so a C++ software developer might use it when speaking of pointer handling or data structures. But when referring to data transfer or network traffic "umleiten" (like in "Verkehr umleiten") is the usual phrase.

Comment: Frankly: I don't really care if it's "strang", I've heard it used in this way from more than one source (*including* the OP who brought it up first). Documenting this is the right thing to do, in my opinion.

Comment: Umlenken, umleiten, umbiegen - alles bildhafte Ausdrücke, die gleichermaßen legitim sind; m.E.

Comment: @feeela and Ray: one can't change that a language is a living thing and what was the wrong of yesterday could be the right of tomorrow. On another note, maybe this meaning of umbiegen should be added to LEO. Does one know how to do that?

Comment: @Eldros: My remark was based only on my personal/professional experience in the IT area including IT reading material, and I have never heard of translating "redirection of a web adress" to "umbiegen", but of course that might be pure chance. Network traffic is something that flows, hence the phrase "umleiten" seems to be a much more natural choice than "umbiegen" (bending is used for non-flowing things like steel bars).

Comment: @Ray: If you see the internet as a [series of tubes](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=intertubes), "umbiegen" might actually fit very well :)

Comment: @OregonGhost: ... and if you see the internet as a series of beautiful flowers, "umtopfen" might fit very well, too ;) If you search google for "webadresse umbiegen" you get zero results and the suggestion to search for "webadresse umleiten" instead, but if you want to emphasize the pointer (and not the traffic) you will get some hits with "link umbiegen" (though not as much as with "umleiten"). Anyway, everyone is free to use his favorite expressions. Language is a creative thing and that is the fun part about it.

Comment: @Ray: I'll be doing my best to get "umtopfen" into usage among my collegues!